# finding the similarity transform connecting two sets of matrices

Tags: linear-transformations, linear-programming, transformation, group-isomorphism, quadratic-programming

Given two set A and B of matrices containing 5 elements. For example:

```
       A                      B
 1     0     0          1     0     0
 0     1     0          0     1     0
 0     0     1          0     0     1

-1    -1    -1          0     1     0
 0     1     0          1     0     0
 0     0     1          0     0     1

-1     0     0         -1     0     0
 0    -1     0          0    -1     0
 0     0    -1          0     0    -1

-1     0     0          0     1     0
 0     0    -1          1     0     0
 0    -1     0          0     0    -1

-1    -1    -1         -1     0     0
 0     0     1          0     0     1
 1     0     0          0    -1     0
```

How can a unique similarity transform be found which maps each matrix in A onto the corresponding matrix in B. In other words, is there an efficient algorithm/method capable of finding $S$ such that $$S A_i S^{-1} = B_i $$ for every i.

Comment: Note that the only matrix similar to the identity matrix is the identity matrix, and thus any similarity transformation will serve to hit your first matching.

Comment: and also as a result the third